# UAC Window On Top

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I seem to be running into a dead end here.  I have a project that does the following:

- just runs and stays in notification area
- when user presses middle mouse button, it shows a form
- user can then chose whatever from the form, and be happy.

This is working just fine, however what is NOT working is that when the form is shown, it does NOT activate.

Now, prior to me modifying the app.manifest to `requireAdmin`, it was working fine.  Any time the form was shown, boom it was active.

But now that i'm running the form as Administrator, given that I need to be able to control one of our other applications with it (that is ran as admin as well), the form comes up just fine, but doesn't activate.

I have tried:
 - `TopMost = true` inside of the Form_Load method
 - Calling `SetForegroundWindow` with the forms handle on Form_Load
 - Calling `ShowDialog` both on Form_Load and also tried it when the form was built.
 - Calling `Activate` on Form_Load as well as when the form was built

Here's my layout:

- Program runs, requires UAC permissions due to the manifest, user agrees, and it kicks off
- Only a notification icon appears, shows a nice little bubble saying it's running
- Program.cs monitors the keyboard/mouse hooks
- When middle mouse button, or any of the keyboard hooks are triggered, it creates a new form object
- sets the location of where the form should appear
- and then finally shows the form.

Again, without UAC and `requireAdmin` inside of the app.manifest, this works fine.  But once it is running as admin, nope, wont stay in front.

I know that MS has made the `SetForegroundWindow` requirements much stricter with later versions of windows (Vista, 7, 8), but i really need to be able to make this form show as the top most, active window (like a context menu).

How can i do that properly?

Comment: You are committing several usability sins.  If you want to ensure your window gets the foreground love then you'll need to use a context menu to activate it.

Comment: Not quite sure what 'sins' you are referring too.  It's not like i'm key logging or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your program into two, a non-admin requiring half that sits in the tray and watches for the middle button, and the half that requires admin permission that you launch when the mouse button is pressed. The non-elevated half could then call `SetForegroundWindow` or `AllowSetForegroundWindow` as needed.

If you want to avoid a UAC prompt every time you can cache a COM elevation object via the `CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin` method and use it repeatedly.