# C# GetProcessByName returning 1 Process when multiple are running

Tags: c#, process, sendkeys

I'm writing a program that lets the user click a link that will open an infopath form and auto-populate some fields for them.

However, since I do not have access to the forms source code to find field variable names, I must enter the information via sending "\t" with SendKeys to the form to reach the appropriate field.  This means that the window must have focus. So I used:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

In order to bring the window to the front.  For some reason, SetForegroundWindow throws a fit if multiple windows of the same process are open and I try to give a process focus... even when I created the process myself and am sure I'm sending the right window, it produces the error message:

```
Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.
```

(This is for the process that I ***just opened.***)

Essentially my code is as follows:

```
Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessByName("InfoPath");
if (ps.Length != 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ps.Length; i ++)
        ps[i].Close();
}

Process infoPath = new Process();
infoPath.StartInfo.FileName = "InfoPath.exe";
infoPath.StartInfo.Arguments = "TemplateLocation.xsn";
infoPath.Start();

try{
    BringToFront(infoPath);
}catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle failure
}

SendKeys.SendWait("\t\t\t\t");
SendKeys.SendWait(information);
```

Where BringToFront is:

```
private void BringToFront(Process pTemp)
{
    try
    {
       SetForegroundWindow(pTemp.MainWindowHandle);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
       //fails here saying that the process has exited, so the requested information is not available.
       throw e;
    }
}
```

The issue that I get is that GetProcessByName only ever returns the most recently opened InfoPath process.  Even though I'll have, say, 5 or 6 running, it returns only the most recently opened one and closes it.

So basically I'm looking for one of two things:

1) Get GetProcessByName to actually return a full list of the infopath processes

or

2) Find out how SetForegroundWindow is failing when I'm sending it a process that I just opened.

Comment: You should be using `Process.GetProcessesByName` (notice the plural). There is no definition for `Process.GetProcessByName` so it leads me to believe you hand-typed this in and there may be other mistakes.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes.. A typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are not bound to GetProcessByName and can use WMI, then this topic may help: [How do I find out what user owns what process programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338534/how-do-i-find-out-what-user-owns-what-process-programmatically). Basically, use the query "Select * from Win32_Process" to enumerate all the processes and filter by executable.
2. Apparently, SetForegroundWindow requires elevated privileges to proceed. You can use the approach described there: [UAC Window On Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294953/uac-window-on-top)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look it up, definitely not bound to GetProcessesByName, just the first thing that I came across that seemed to suit my purposes!

Answer (score 0):

So whats likely happening is infopath spawns a new process for the UI window and the parent process exits. So you instantly open infopath.exe but the process ID returned is not the ultimate UI process. You are better off searching by window title if you are looking to get a specific UI window. User32.dll has a method to help you here:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr className, string lpWindowName);
```

You can pass IntPtr.Zero to className.